# Android, any way to make one view group stays the same orientation with others changes, when change device orientation

Tags: android

is there any way I can make that when I change the device orientation, a view group and views within it stays the same orientations (but other views, view groups, bars, and everything else change the orientation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to limit just single view or fragment supported orientation in a activity. I guess that it is not possible from the design of activity. However, I find a way to walk around way and achieve the same goal. Instead of limit views' supported orientation, every view could be rotated at first, then rotated back those views need to stay the same.
https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout 
This helps a lot.
Follow the example in the project, it will work like a charm.Two more things need to mention:
1. Don't override onConfigurationChanged for your activity.
2. Don't set android:configChanges for the activity in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

You can make a different layout for better support of the device orientation change.
Taken from Android Documentation, [Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

> If you want to provide a special layout for landscape, then you need to use a land qualifier:

```
MyProject/
    res/
       layout/              # default (portrait)
           main.xml

       layout-land/         # landscape
           main.xml
```

Comment: it doesn't really solve the problem. For example, what if those views' positions in the view group is determined by users?